# How to protect my laptop screen from being hacked?

Tags: hardware, physical, van-eck-phreaking

My laptop screen has been hacked, and I think that it is by Van Eck phreaking method. The attackers can see my screen, they are seeing my screen right now. I never even talk to them and these attackers, whom are actually my neighbors. I heard them talking about this event (I'm typing this text) right now. I use Windows 7, there is a turned on wi-Fi connection, but the bluetooth is turned off. I scanned my laptop with anti-malware, but there was nothing, not even any trojan. It is not only my neighbors, but many people, I think, can see what I'm typing right now. I know that It sounds crazy and paranoid, but those are the facts. I basically just want to protect my laptop. Is there any way to protect my laptop screen from being hacked?

Comment: This is not what SE is for. Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36544/discussion-on-question-by-tita-van-eck-phreaking).

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I have tried everything and they still can see my laptop screen.

Comment: While I'm sure it's not Van Eck phreaking, if you really are concerned that that is the issue, perhaps read up more about how it works. One of the original TEMPEST papers explains a few mitigations, such as using vertical filters, reducing contrast, and ensuring that foreground and background always use the same number of subpixels (e.g. pure green text on pure blue background. Horrible for the eyes, but also horrible for a phreaker).

Comment: Also, I'll just say what everyone is thinking right now. This is pretty indicative of paranoid schizophrenia. That's not meant to be an insult, but "I just know that they're talking about me and see this right now" is the _sine qua non_ of such paranoia.

Answer (score 10):

No, you are most certainly not the victim of Van Eck phreaking.

You know when you feel a bit sick, and you do some googeling and even though you are not a doctor you are suddenly convinced your sympthoms exactly match those of some obscure form of cancer? Then when you tell your doctor he or she sighs and say, no, your not having cancer. Yeah, that is what is going to happen here.

I understand that it might seem like Van Eck prheaking is the only possible explanation. But in fact there are many more far more likely explanations (listed here from more likely to less likely in my opinion):

- Your neigbhours do not know what's on your screen. You just misheard them or misunderstood them, making you believe they know.
- They found out some completely different way. If they know what you wrote in an email, maybe the person you sent it to told them? Maybe you told them about the word document you were writing, but forgot you did. Maybe you told someone else that told them. Maybe they heard you talk about it through the wall.
- They have peaked through a window or maybe you left the door open one day or maybe you used the file they have information about on a public computer where they found it.
- Maybe you are the victim of some other kind of hacking attack. They might have been able to infect your computer with spying software. (And no, that you ran some scans does not mean it isn't there.) They might be snooping on your WiFi.

I'm not saying any of these explanations are correct. I am sure you can come up with convincing arguments that some of them are not correct. What I am trying to say that there are many, many possible explanations, some of whish you might not even think about, that are far more likely then your neighbours Van Eck phreaking you.

So why not Van Eck phreaking?

- It would be an insanely complicated method to do something quite simple - to figure out what is on your neighbours computer. Why would anyone pick the hardest tool to use when there are easier alternatives?
- While Van Eck prheaking has been demonstrated to work, it is seldom practical to use in real situations (that is, "in the wild").
- When it works (it doesnt always work) it only works on small distances, and even a thin wall might make it impossible.
- There is no universal Van Eck mashine that works on all devices. They would need to have something custom made for your laptop model *and* you phone model.

Comment: They *might* even be hijacking bluetooth devices; a keyboard would give them all the keystrokes, and a headset, the sound. IMO, it would be way easier (and with better results) than snooping on his WiFi communications. :-)

Comment: I think they will not be able to do that too. It is a pure 'wild' neighborhood.

Comment: Actually Van Eck phreaking tends to work for pretty large distances, and through thick walls. Around 100 meters is not uncommon.